# Ebean enhancement in subproject Play 2.4

Tags: ebean, playframework-2.4

i have an application that connects to two databases, default database models are in the root project and the second database models are in the sub-project.
my projects, a brief folder structure looks something like so

```
[root]/build.sbt
[root]/conf/application.conf
[root]/app/models/Author.java (and other models)
[root]/module/build.sbt 
[root]/module/app/mods/User.java
```

and the application.conf has ebean configured like so

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/main"
db.default.username=postgres
db.default.password="password"

db.second.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.second.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/second"
db.second.username=postgres
db.second.password="password"

ebean.default = ["models."]
ebean.second = ["mods."]
```

and the build.sbt like this:

```
lazy val module = project.in(file("module")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, PlayEnhancer)
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
.aggregate(module)
.dependsOn(module)
```

but when i run the app i get this exception

```
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class mods.User is not enhanced?
```

obviously the models in the subproject are not being enhanced. How do i get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the below in the `build.sbt` of your sub-project:

```
playEbeanModels in Compile := Seq("mods.*")
```

This tells the Play Framework to also look at your sub-project when looking for model classes. You can find a longer explanation in the paragraph *"Configuring the sbt plugin"* in the [Play Framework Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean).

This solution worked for me (after reloading and compiling the project).